# Perl System Grep and Paste

Tags: perl, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

> Dog
>   
> Bulldog
> Terrier
>
> Cat
>   
> Persian
>
> Ape
>   
> Gorilla
>
> Dog
>   
> Pitbull
> Lab
> Shepard
> Husky

I want to be able to search for each line containing dog and select everything until the next empty line and put it into a new file.

I want an output file like:

> Dog
>   
> Bulldog
> Terrier
>
> Dog
>   
> Pitbull
> Lab
> Shepard
> Husky

I know I can use grep to find the word dog but how can I use it, or with what can I use it, so that it grabs everything after it UNTIL the next empty line and moves it into another file.

I am writing a script in Perl to do this because there are other things I wish to add on that are made easier with Perl. I was going to use `system(grep....)` to find the word but I wasn't sure what to do after that.

I will also note that I want to be able to do this recursively. I have many files that look like what I had shown and I would like to extract the Dog block from all of them. So it would be something recursive from the directory.

Comment: Please check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/multiline-regex-blank-line-delimiters It should give you a head start.

Comment: @DanTheMan That worked perfectly! All I had to do was make it recursive and it did it through multiple files for me. Thanks for referring it!

Comment: `perl -00 -wne'print if /^Dog/' files`, where `files` is some specification for files that you can come up in your shell.  Or, perhaps build the list and pipe that over `ls -1R dir/*txt | xargs perl -00 -wne'print if /^Dog/'` (where I can imagine use of `find` or `grep` instead of that token `ls`) But I'd suggest to write a script, as this is a very nice exercise to get you into that

Comment: (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57987011/4653379) for example of piping data from a tool that builds a file list to another which process them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perl -ne 'print if /^Dog/../^$/' file`

The `..` and `...` operators in perl can join two conditionals.  From the time that the first evaluates true until the second conditional evaluates true, the joined conditional will evaluate true.   So you want to `print` from the time `$_ =~ m/^Dog/` is true until `$_ =~ m/^\s+$/` is true.  The above is shorthand for that.

The distinction between `..` vs `...` is not important here because in this case, the conditionals cannot both be true on the same line.

Comment: Yes, the [range operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators),  nice :)

Comment: I have a question regarding this. If I want to print all dog blocks that contain the word bulldog within the block, is there any way to do this? or is not possible specify another restriction by string content

Comment: @sfr you have to save the range to print (or not) at the end.  ie  `push @l if /^Dog/../^$/; print @l if /^$/ && grep /bulldog/, @l; @l=() if /^$/`.

Comment: Again, there are a lot of implicit `$_` in the above suggestion.  Push the line into `@l` if it's in the range, then print the entire range if perl's `grep` matches bulldog to any substring of any item in the `@l` array.

Answer (score 3):

IF you can use `awk`, then this can be done.  By setting Record Selector to nothing `awk` works in block mode.  Test if block starts with `dog`, and if yes do the default action, print the block.

```
awk '/^Dog/' ORS="\n\n" RS="" file
Dog
Bulldog
Terrier

Dog
Pitbull
Lab
Shepard
Husky
```